# how can we force locale in android app depending on buildType in gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to use only english language in release build and multiple languages in debug build. I am able to achieve this using ProductFlavour but not with buildType.

```
productFlavors {
        english {
            resConfigs "en" 
        }
        french {
            resConfigs "en", "fr" 
        }
    }
```

I'm using resConfig.. but it cant be used under buildTypes.
If i try using it under buildTypes, build fails and I'm getting below error:

Gradle DSL does not found: resConfigs()

Any help will be really appreciated

one more question in the same line. I have scenario, where I need to use default values only when QA_BUILD is false.
My build.gradle looks like this:

debug { 
    buildConfigField "boolean", "QA_BUILD", "false" 
} 
integration { 
    buildConfigField "boolean", "QA_BUILD", "false" 
} 
release { 
    buildConfigField "boolean", "QA_BUILD", "true" 
}

Comment: @Alex.F any solution which I can try for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have only the default (English) values, and you want to control that through the build process you can exclude the localized folders (i.e. `values-fr`) from the release build.
Just put the folders you only want to be compiled for `debug` in `src/debug/...`